# Ad networks for web apps made with phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, leadbolt, mobfox

Are there ad networks like leadbolt or mobfox where they give you html code which can be inserted into my phonegap app without needing to install a sdk. For example leadbolt has 
script type="text/javascript" src="http://ad.leadboltads.net/show_app_ad.js?     section_id="id"
Which creates a banner ad.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you couldn't use one of those solutions you mentioned in your phonegap app. If it's web based app, then leadbolt's js code should work fine.

Comment: yea I like leadbolt and i'am using it at the moment, however they only have banner ads.Was hoping for other ad networks so I could mix up ad formats.

Comment: Oh, so you want other ads like interstitials and such?